# Tilted exhaust gases from the rocket nozzle after sonic boom

Tags: rockets, fuel, solid-fuel, amateur-rocketry

Our solid propellant rocket, on test, produces sonic boom. Right after,  the plume of exhaust tilts sideways. This will definitely have a gimbal effect during flight. The propellant chamber has one hole in the center to increase the burn surface area. I am assuming that the shock produced that shakes the propellant chamber crumbles the unburnt fuel inside. This affects the fuel burn and mass flow resulting in the tilting of the plume at the nozzle.

We have fixed fins and the nozzle cannot be gimballed to correct the direction.
Is there a way to correct this situation?[image: Tilted Plume after sonic boom]

Comment: Sonic boom or just BOOM ?

Comment: Hello@AJN,  I am not sure how to differentiate between the two. My effective exhaust velocity is 1264 m/s(Mach 4) so I assumed it was sonic boom.

Comment: I was referring to the nozzle failure in the answer posted.

Comment: @AJN , the nozzle was just fine. I believe its because the nozzle was loosely placed, the turbulence created the boom. Will correct that next test.

Comment: @RocketHack sorry to say, your question may be closed because of a site-wide ban on discussing rocket projects because of legal issues: https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1032/11855

Comment: Hello @0xDBFB7, Is there another forum you could refer me where I can ask more of rocket questions without worrying about the restrictions. We are a student led team preparing to compete in Spaceport cup America 2022 and need as much help as possible.Sadly, we don't have an active advisor and looking for one.

Comment: Hi @Rocket Hack  I'm afraid I don't know any rocket building communities :( A search for people (professors, maybe?) with so-called "High Powered Rocketry certificates" at universities might perhaps be useful, or search for HPR clubs. Hope you find the solution!

Comment: It looks like there are some good high-powered rocketry forums on the net, though I'm not familiar with any of them.

Answer (score 5):

What is the condition of the nozzle after burnout? is it asymmetrically eroded? That points to nozzle failure.

If it is spitting chunky sparks, then your fuel grain is fracturing and you are operating not a rocket motor but a malfunctioning bomb. It is absolutely vital that your fuel grain remain mechanically intact and adhered to the sidewalls of the motor during firing, or really bad things can happen.
Is your motor sidewall possibly not rigid enough?

Comment: The nozzle is in fine condition. No erosion that I noticed. Initially, there is smooth burn for about 3 sec, then the boom happens. You are also correct about the the combustion chamber not being properly harnessed. It had been moving/shifting around from t = 2 sec. We will get it supported better next time. Thank you. That was helpful.

Comment: When you say 'chunky sparks', is it like the ones in the pic above?

Comment: @RocketHack Pretty much so, yes. Those sparks, if not part of your ignition system, are definitely *something* that is not normal exhaust. They seem to be particulate, do not follow the roughly aerodynamic flow of the main exhaust, and seem to be larger and much fewer in number. It points to either erosion of something, or fragmented fuel being spit out in largely unburned state.(or possibly just photo artifact from the exhaust impinging on a deflecting baffle. One fuzzy photo is not very clear)